# How To Merge Result In MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table as an example:

```
  id   | ItemName | BullNum
-------|----------|-------------
  1    | Test     |    1
  2    | cars     |    1
  3    | Tomato   |    2
  4    | Cat      |    2
  5    | Dog      |    2
```

I need to write a SQL query to give me a result like this:

```
  id   | ItemName       | BullNum
-------|----------------|-------------
  1    | Test cars      |    1
  2    | Tomato Cat Dog |    2
```

Comment: Please show the code that generates your error.

Comment: Looks like you need a `GROUP BY` or `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Are you referring to SQL Pivots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like aggregation:

```
select row_number() over (order by bullnum) as id,
       group_concat(itemname separator ' ') as itemnames,
       bullnum
from t
group by bullnum;
```